# dyld: Symbol not found: _ERR_remove_thread_state

Tags: libtorrent

I’m trying to run the make_torrent example code provide over [here](https://github.com/arvidn/libtorrent/blob/master/examples/make_torrent.cpp).

I’m have compiled and installed libtorrent based on what written over [here](http://libtorrent.org/building.html#step-2-running-configure)

Here how I have complied and linked the make_torrent.cc file.

```
g++ -g -Wall make_torrent.cc -ltorrent-rasterbar -lboost_system -o make_torrent
```

Upon running the make_torrent sample code I see this

```
usage: make_torrent FILE [OPTIONS]

Generates a torrent file from the specified file
or directory and writes it to standard out

OPTIONS:
-m file       generate a merkle hash tree torrent.
              merkle torrents require client support
              the resulting full merkle tree is written to
              the specified file
-w url        adds a web seed to the torrent with
              the specified url
-t url        adds the specified tracker to the
              torrent. For multiple trackers, specify more
              -t options
-c comment    sets the comment to the specified string
-C creator    sets the created-by field to the specified string
-p bytes      enables padding files. Files larger
              than bytes will be piece-aligned
-s bytes      specifies a piece size for the torrent
              This has to be a multiple of 16 kiB
-l            Don't follow symlinks, instead encode them as
              links in the torrent file
-o file       specifies the output filename of the torrent file
              If this is not specified, the torrent file is
              printed to the standard out, except on windows
              where the filename defaults to a.torrent
-r file       add root certificate to the torrent, to verify
              the HTTPS tracker
-S info-hash  add a similar torrent by info-hash. The similar
              torrent is expected to share some files with this one
-L collection add a collection name to this torrent. Other torrents
              in the same collection is expected to share files
              with this one.
-M            make the torrent compatible with mutable torrents
              this means aligning large files and pad them in order
              for piece hashes to uniquely indentify a file without
              overlap
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ERR_remove_thread_state
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.9.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _ERR_remove_thread_state
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtorrent-rasterbar.9.dylib
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I know I have to provide the relevant argument to make torrent but I’m not sure why libtorrent is complaining about the linker

```
g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by not linking to openssl correctly. I'm assuming you're on OSX, which has an old version of openssl in the default install path.

I would suggest installing openssl with `brew install openssl`. Note that this requires you have homebrew installed.
After doing this, do brew info openssl and look lines telling you what to add to your `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS`. In my case:

```
For compilers to find this software you may need to set:
    LDFLAGS:  -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
    CPPFLAGS: -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include
For pkg-config to find this software you may need to set:
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig
```

So in my case, I would then compile with:

```
g++ -g -Wall -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include make_torrent.cc -ltorrent-rasterbar -lboost_system -o make_torrent
```

If this does not work, I would also make sure that you include these flags when compiling libtorrent.